# How to save media files on AWS with multiple EC2 instances on AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

In my application; users can upload videos and I want to keep them on file system and not in database. If I use Amazon Web Services ( AWS ) and use only one EC2 instance with EBS ( for storage ) its fine.
But if I use auto-scaling or multiple EC2 instances ; then if user uploads the video it gets saved on one of the EC2 ( associated with one of EBS ) . Next time if user logs in ( or if session stickiness is not there; then if the user's next request goes to another EC2 instance ) how will it access his video ?

What is the best solution for this problem ? Is using S3 the only solution but for that I cant simply do java.io.File .. I think then I will have to use AWS SDK api to access the uploaded videos.. but wont that be slower ?

Is there any better solution ?

Comment: With S3, the file can be directly downloaded to the browser, without going through EC2. That is potentially faster, too.

Comment: How many and how much size of video files we are talking here ?

Comment: max 5 - 10 mb .. it shouldnt exceed that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use Amazon S3. It's fast, relatively cheap and works well if you are using other Amazon Web Services.

You could upload to the EC2 instance first and use Simple Workflow Servie to transfer the files centrally automatically. This is also useful if you want to re-encode the video to a multiple bit-rates later.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the information. I felt that S3 is quite slow.

Comment: @Deepak If you make sure your s3 account and your ec2 account are in the same region (ie. eu-west or us-east) transfer will be super fast as they are in the same datacenter.

Comment: s3 is indeed slow but you can pair it with cloudfront to serve the files. Its easy to setup and hyperfast when you pair the two.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup NAS. It can be NFS or something like GlusterFS. The later is modern and it scales well...